# Setar texto do item selecionado no Spinner para um EditText

Tags: java, android

Antes de tudo perdoem a falta de conhecimento e os erros técnicos, estou iniciando na área.

Preciso enviar a informação de um spinner para um banco de dados e a solução que eu  propus foi setar o texto do item selecionado para um EditText e desse EditText ser enviado para o banco de dados.

Esse EditText fica em um AlertDialog no AdapterHistorico.java fora do meu fragmento FragmentoHistorico.java.

Eis aqui o código do AlertDialog:

```
 private void editTaskDialog(final DataHistorico pedidos){



    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_edt_pedido, null);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) subView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemSelectedListener());



    final EditText campoId = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Id);
    final EditText campoCliente = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Cliente);
    final EditText campoStatus = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Status);
    final EditText campoEndereco = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Endereco);
    final EditText campoTotal = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Total);

    if(pedidos != null){
        campoId.setText(pedidos.getId());
        campoCliente.setText(pedidos.getCliente());
        campoStatus.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getStatus()));
        campoEndereco.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getEndereco()));
        campoTotal.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getTotal()));
    }


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Editar pedido");
    builder.setView(subView);
    builder.create();

    builder.setPositiveButton("SALVAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final String id = campoId.getText().toString();
            final String cliente = campoCliente.getText().toString();
            final String status = campoStatus.getText().toString();
            final String endereco = campoEndereco.getText().toString();
            final String total = campoTotal.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cliente) || TextUtils.isEmpty(status) || TextUtils.isEmpty(endereco) || TextUtils.isEmpty(total)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Algo está errado. Cheque os dados digitados.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{

                new ServiceLogin().execute(id, cliente, endereco, status, total);
            }
        }
    });



    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


           //DynamicToast.make(context, "Operação cancelada.", AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_pedido_em_andamento), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#000000"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Operação cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

E logo abaixo a classe ItemSelectedListener:

```
public class ItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    final EditText campoStatus = (EditText) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.etStatusAux);

    //get strings of first item
    String firstItem = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {



        if (firstItem.equals(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()))) {
            //campoStatus.setText("");
        } else {
            campoStatus.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg) {

    }

}
```

Qualquer forma que eu tente não funciona ou o app fecha quando o onItemSelected é ativado como é o caso dessa linha que eu fiz passando o contexto do AdapterHistorico:

```
final EditText campoStatus = (EditText) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Status);
```

EDIT:

Log do erro:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.beliasdev.cadjobel.adapter.AdapterHistorico$ItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(AdapterHistorico.java:227)

Acho que o Spinner esta trabalhando num contexto diferente do AlertDialog por isso ocorre o erro e o app fecha após um item ser selecionado.

Caso alguém tenha uma solução melhor para meu problema de enviar a informação do spinner junto dos outros EditTexts no AlertDialog para a database sinta-se a vontade para opinar.

EDIT 2:

```
public class AdapterHistorico extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


private String cancelado;
private String dateold;
private String datenew;
private String concluido;
private String em_andamento;
private String status;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataHistorico> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataHistorico current;
int currentPos=0;


// create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
public AdapterHistorico(Context context, List<DataHistorico> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}


// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_historico, parent,false);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {


    // Aqui você está apto a obter o valor selecionado!
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();


}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}



// Bind data
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   final DataHistorico pedidos = data.get(position);

    // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    DataHistorico current = data.get(position);



    /* if (current.pStatus.equals("concluido")) {
        // ToDo when first item is selected
    }

   if(current.pStatus == "") {
        spinner.setSelection(getIndex(spinner, "concluido"));
    }*/

    dateold = current.pData;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 'ás' HH:mm:ss");
        datenew = df2.format(format.parse(dateold));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    myHolder.txtPedidoCliente.setText(current.pCliente);

    myHolder.txtPedidoData.setText(datenew);

    myHolder.txtPedidoTotal.setText("R$ " + current.pTotal);

    myHolder.edtPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            editTaskDialog(pedidos);
        }
    });


    // load image into imageview using glide
    concluido = "concluido";
    cancelado = "cancelado";
    em_andamento= "em_andamento";
    status = current.pStatus;
    if (status.equals(concluido)) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_pedido_concluido).into(myHolder.imgPedidoStatus);
    } else if (status.equals(cancelado)) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_pedido_cancelado).into(myHolder.imgPedidoStatus);
    }else if (status.equals(em_andamento)) {
        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_pedido_em_andamento).into(myHolder.imgPedidoStatus);
    }


}



// return total item from List
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}



private void editTaskDialog(final DataHistorico pedidos){

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_edt_pedido, null);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) subView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // Adicionado

    final EditText campoId = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Id);
    final EditText campoCliente = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Cliente);
    final EditText campoStatus = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Status);
    final EditText campoEndereco = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Endereco);
    final EditText campoTotal = (EditText)subView.findViewById(R.id.etPedido_Total);

    if(pedidos != null){
        campoId.setText(pedidos.getId());
        campoCliente.setText(pedidos.getCliente());
        campoStatus.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getStatus()));
        campoEndereco.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getEndereco()));
        campoTotal.setText(String.valueOf(pedidos.getTotal()));
    }


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Editar pedido");
    builder.setView(subView);
    builder.create();

    builder.setPositiveButton("SALVAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final String id = campoId.getText().toString();
            final String cliente = campoCliente.getText().toString();
            final String status = campoStatus.getText().toString();
            final String endereco = campoEndereco.getText().toString();
            final String total = campoTotal.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cliente) || TextUtils.isEmpty(status) || TextUtils.isEmpty(endereco) || TextUtils.isEmpty(total)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Algo está errado. Cheque os dados digitados.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{

                new ServiceLogin().execute(id, cliente, endereco, status, total);
            }
        }
    });



    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


           //DynamicToast.make(context, "Operação cancelada.", AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_pedido_em_andamento), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#000000"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Operação cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


private class ServiceLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private String res;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
                "", "Aguarde...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        res = null;
        PutUtility put = new PutUtility();

        put.setParam("id", params[0].toString());
        put.setParam("pedido_cliente", params[1].toString());
        put.setParam("pedido_endereco", params[2].toString());
        put.setParam("pedido_status", params[3].toString());
        put.setParam("pedido_total", params[4].toString());

        try {
            res = put.postData("http://10.0.2.2/cadjobel/public/edt-pedido-app.php");
            Log.v("res", res);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        DynamicToast.makeSuccess(context, "Pedido editado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtPedidoCliente;
    ImageView imgPedidoStatus;
    TextView txtPedidoData;
    TextView txtPedidoTotal;
    ImageView edtPedido;


    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtPedidoCliente= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPedidoCliente);
        imgPedidoStatus= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPedidoStatus);
        txtPedidoData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPedidoData);
        txtPedidoTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPedidoTotal);
        edtPedido = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtPedido);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Boa noite, João Victor! Para ficar mais fácil descobrir o que há de errado com seu código, edite sua pergunta e inclua alguma mensagem de erro que apareça no log.

Comment: Ah desculpe, esqueci de incluir o erro que aparece no log. Já foi editado.

Comment: Esse fluxo de obter dados em `AlertDialog`, de chamadas assíncronas à bases de dados e tals, geralmente dá pra se resolver utilizando o padrão communicator... Acho que se aplica no seu caso

Comment: Especificamente falando, em relação ao erro, você está tentando instanciar uma view que é o `EditTextView` em um lugar nada aproprieado e fazendo `cast` de uma referência do Context nula

Comment: Vou tentar reorganizar seu código e resolver seu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você requisita, é preciso obter o item selecionado do `Spinner`. Retire a instanciação dele de dentro do método `editTaskDialog` e coloque no `onCreate` da `Activity`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_spinner);
}
```

Agora sua `Activity`deverá implementar a interface com os métodos de retorno da seleção

```
public class NomeDaSuaActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    /*...*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_spinner);
               spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // Adicionado
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        // Aqui você está apto a obter o valor selecionado!
        int item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Por fim, `ItemSelectedListener` não faz mais sentido pra nós e, em teoria, seu problema é resolvido já que é ele que está causando a bagunça. Lembrando que `ItemSelectedListener` que a `Activity` implementa não é a classe que você criou.

Você tem agora que desacoplar o o botão do adapter, da seguinte forma: crie uma interface

```
public interface Communicator<T> {
   void onEvent(T data);
}
```

Ela vai ser útil para comunicarmos o evento de clique do adapter até a `Activity`. Implemente essa interface na `Activity`, mude o método `editTaskDialog` para ela e passe uma referência para seu adapter

```
public class NomeDaSuaActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, Communicator<seu_tipo_de_objeto> {
        private SeuAdapter mAdapter;
        /*...*/

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           mAdapter = new SeuAdapter(this); // Passando uma referência para acionar o evento
           Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_spinner);
                   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // Adicionado
        }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // Aqui você está apto a obter o valor selecionado!
            int item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

        @override
        public void onEvent(seu_tipo_de_objeto data) {
            /* Finalmente chame editTaskDialog */
           this.editTaskDialog();
        }

        public void editTaskDialog() {
            /*...*/
        } 
    }
```

Sempre que o botão for clicado no adapter você deve acionar o `onEvent`, da seguinte forma

Anexe um evento de clique no botão, na classe do `ViewHolder` e adicione essa classe à classe do adapter pra facilitar o uso `listener.onEvent()`

```
protected class SeuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
  implements View.OnClickListener{
    public Button seuBotao;

    /*...*/

    public SeuViewHolder(View v) {
         seuBotao = v.findViewById(R.id.id_do_botao);
         seuBotao.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if(v.getId() == R.id.id_do_botao) {
         TipoDoSeuObjeto data = seuListaDeObj.get(getAdapterPosition());

         /* Isso aciona o método que vai abrir seu dialog na Activity */
         listener.onEvent(data);
       }
    }
}
```

E por fim, no seu adapter faça o seguinte

```
   private Communicator<seu_tipo_de_objeto> listener;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterHistorico(Context context, List<DataHistorico> data, Communicator<seu_tipo_de_objeto> listener){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_historico, parent,false);

        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }
```

Dessa forma, coisas que não podiam feitas no adapter, ficam na `Activity`. Você pode adaptar o códgio para um `Fragment`  se quiser. Mude `seu_tipo_de_objeto` na interface para o tipo de objeto que deseja enviar. Isso certamente resolve o problema, só adapte-o ao seu código.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Mas se eu tirar a instanciação de dentro do método editTaskDialog o app da um crash pq o spinner aparece na mesma view do editTaskDialog e por isso precisa estar dentro do mesmo método.

Comment: E onde seu método `editTaskDialog` está?

Comment: Dentro da classe AdapterHistorico.

Comment: `public class AdapterHistorico extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {...

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {...

public void onItemSelected(...
...
private void editTaskDialog(final DataHistorico pedidos){
        
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_edt_pedido, null); 

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) subView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
...`

Comment: @JoaoVictorMenom, edita tua pergunta com o código. No comentária não pra entender nada

Comment: Tenho um fragmento e nesse fragmento tem um ListView que está no AdapterHistorico.java e nesta mesma classe que está contido o editTaskDialog

Comment: ok, vou editar.

Comment: Por que ao você está usando uma adapter para `RecyclerView` com um `ListView`? Porque não usa um `RecyclerView`

Comment: "_Esse EditText fica em um AlertDialog no AdapterHistorico.java fora do meu fragmento FragmentoHistorico.java._",  você deve criar o `AlertDialog` dentro da `Activity`/`Fragment` e não no `adapter`. Ele deve se preocupar apenas com a lista.

Comment: é um RecycleView mesmo, não ListView, me confundi.

Comment: É por que no RecycleView tem um botão que quando é clicado o AlertDialog é mostrado, e como o RecycleView  fica no adapter eu coloquei o AlertDialog lá.

Comment: Entendi qual sua intenção. Cada item da lista deve ter um botão que quando clicado abre o `AlertDialog`, é isso?

Comment: Isso, os itens do RecycleView são retornados da database e  tem um botão de editar em cada um dos itens.

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta para se enquadrar no seu problema